# Problemas com o Input submit e reset

Tags: html, input

Por qual motivo os 2 elementos input colocados no final do código não estão fazendo nada?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://Example.com" method="get">
        <div>
            <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" size="10" required="nome"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
            <input type="password" id="senha" size="5" maxlength="6" required="senha"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <fieldset align="center">
         <h3>Se você gostou, não deixe de avaliar</h3>
         <label><input type="radio" name="avaliar" value="b"/>Bom</label>
         <label><input type="radio" name="avaliar" value="m"/>Médio</label>
         <label><input type="radio" name="avaliar" value="r"/>Ruim</label>

         <label for="comments"></label>
         <br/>
         <textarea rows="6" cols="40"></textarea>
         <br/>
         <label><input type="submit" name="Enviar"></label>
         <label><input type="reset" value="Apagar"></label>
         <br/>     
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

O type reset não deveria apagar os textos e o submit redirecionar ao Example.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc colocou seus `inputs` submit e reset fora da tag `<form>`, então para ter um btn fora do `form`, mas fazer referencia a ele vc precisa usar o atributo `form=""` na tag do `<input>`, e nesse `form=""` vc coloca o nome que vc declarar no `ID` que vc colocar na tag `<form>`

**Exemplo:**
No input o form ficaria assim: `<input form="meuForm" type="submit">`

E na tag do form vc coloca um id: `<form id="meuForm">`

Como abaixo

```html
<form action="https://Example.com" method="get" id="meuForm">
    <div>
        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nome" size="10" required="nome"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
        <input type="password" id="senha" size="5" maxlength="6" required="senha"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Cadastrar</button>
    </div>
</form>
<fieldset align="center">
      <h3>Se você gostou, não deixe de avaliar</h3>
      <label><input type="radio" name="avaliar" value="b"/>Bom</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="avaliar" value="m"/>Médio</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="avaliar" value="r"/>Ruim</label>

      <label for="comments"></label>
      <br/>
      <textarea rows="6" cols="40"></textarea>
      <br/>
      <label><input type="submit" name="Enviar" form="meuForm"></label>
      <label><input type="reset" value="Apagar" form="meuForm"></label>
      <br/>     
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ambos devem estar dentro do formulário, no seu caso, você está fechando a tag `form` antes dos input.